# Blender Add-on: Import-Export Three.JS doesn't activate

Tags: add-on, three.js

I added the io_three folder from three.js to Blender's add-ons.

When I go to Blender user preferences, the three.js addon appears, but it prevents me from activating it. 
The warning says "importer not included."

[image]

[image: Details in Warning Panel]

^ Report inside warning panel.

Comment: are you familiar with manually installing add-ons ? like dragging/duplicating the io_three folder from the downloaded mr doob three.js directory into `.../scripts/addons_contrib/io_three`  ?

Comment: I would install it this way: http://blender.stackexchange.com/revisions/42841/3

Comment: @zeffii I just wanted to point out that after copying `three.js/utils/exporters/blender/addons/io_three/` to `~/.config/blender/2.78/scripts/addons`, I could not actually check the box. The only thing that worked was restarting blender a couple times.

Answer (score 2):

The warning on the UI

[image]

is only telling you this is an Exporter add-on only. "Importer not included". Everyone using that version of the add-on will see that warning. It's not an error, if you look at the files in the three.js  repository ([blender/addons/io_three](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/utils/exporters/blender/addons/io_three))  you'll see that there's only an Exporter.

As for the report in the Warning panel, that's different.

Comment: while it may be only a warning, if the box still can't be checked, try restarting blender and going back to the plugins page a couple times. If you can't get it to work after restarting blender, then you do actually have a problem. cheers

Comment: the checkbox and that Warning "Importer not included" are two entirely different things.

Comment: right. I couldn't mark the checkbox until I restarted blender.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem was happening to me. When I click on the activate button, it just wouldn't activate. I just closed Blender and restarted it and then it worked.

Comment: The same thing happened to me. I kept clicking the box and waiting for a few seconds in case there was lag. It simply didn't work. I restarted blender, and - even though I saw the same warning about the importer as you did - the checkbox actually worked after the restart and allowed the add-on to be added within blender.